# Arduino LED PWM dimmer starts blinking on low PWM values

Tags: pwm, transistor

I'm trying to build a PWM led dimmer with Arduino using this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS3Zhs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Everything works fine until the pin PWM 3 drops below the analog value 50 (more or less) the LEDs starts blinking fast and noticeably. *However, if I touch with my finger the metal cup of the BJT transistor the LEDs do not blink anymore and they work as I assumed.* The test program is below, and I've tested it with an Arduino UNO and an Arduino MEGA and they both have the same problem. The DC supplier is a transformer I bought from an electronics shop and it works properly if directly attached to the strip.

Test Program:

```
void setup(){
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  for(int i = 0;i<=255;i++){
    analogWrite(3,i);
    delay( i<=40 ? 300 : 50);
  }

  for(int i = 255;i>=0;i--){
    analogWrite(3,i);
    delay( i<=40 ? 300 : 50);
  }
}
```

I tried searching my problem on the internet and I've found a schematic which uses a P2N2222 transistor [in this article](https://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/Driving_LEDs_with_CMOS_and_TTL_Outputs/Driving_an_LED_Using_Transistors.html), which is equivalent to mine, except for the fact that it uses a P2N2222. I also tried changing the transistor to a new one (in case the one I'm using is broken), but it did not help.

So I don't see what I did wrong, could you please help me in finding it out?

Comment: Did you write the program yourself? That is okay. The schematic is wrong, when you connect it that way, the transistor, the arduino board and perhaps the ledstrip as well are blown. When using 24v, you could damage your computer as well via the usb cable. Tell us more about the led strip. Can you give a link to it? How much voltage and current does it need?

Comment: The led strip requires 24V and 500mA of current. I have no links for that because I bought it from an electronics store a long time ago. I've already tried the schematic shown and it did not damage anything... why should it damage a component?

Comment: Looking at the schematic, it seems like the LED and the transistor are upside down.

Comment: Your diagram has the transistor wired backwards. It should not work that way.

Comment: You're right. I've corrected it: I just flipped the transistor in the schematic, but the circuit I've designed is the corrected one and it has the aforementioned problem for small analog values of the pin. Thank you.

Comment: Can you do a vertical flip of the led as well?

Comment: LTL307-EE is a regular red led (2V,  20 mA) Something that survives 24V and consumes 500 mA ( which is a lot for a 2N2222 btw ) and your power source they both must have some electronics inside, which might behave in strange ways when switched by your PWM transistor.

Comment: since you are editing your schematic, move the GND on the uno to one of the bottom pins and get rid of the crossover at the transistor base

Comment: How many LEDs in this strip? If there were 12 2V 20mA LEDs you could put them in series and drive them with ≈20mA of 24V. 500mA of 24V is a whole bunch of juice for LEDs.

Comment: I updated the question with all the details. @DuncanC I don't know how the LEDs are connected to the stripe because I bought the entire stripe from an electronics shop. I can only make hypothesis. I see that those LEDs are connected in series at least every 6 LEDs (the stripe can be cut every six LEDs), but I suppose that the 6 LEDs are connected in parallel because if a LED stops working, the others will work as regular. Anyway, I measured the current of 500mA by connecting the stripe and measuring the current with an amperometer in order to calculate the resistor R1

Comment: As DataFiddler says, the LED strip may well have electronics in it that get confused when you feed it pulsed power at too low a duty cycle. Without more info about the LED strip it’s impossible to tell for sure.